# Setting the label of the lightning button through aura:set

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

I am trying to change the label of the lightning button component using aura:set like below, doing wrong somewhere, this doesn't seem to work.

```
<lightning:button>
    Active : 
        <aura:set attribute="label" value="{! v.building.activeUnits }">

        </aura:set>
</lightning:button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use both the body and the label attribute at once. The body overrides the label. Instead, use one or the other. Here's an example of each in an app so you can see it in action.

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <aura:attribute name="label1" type="String" default="Hello World" />
    <aura:attribute name="label2" type="String" default="Hello World" />
    <lightning:button onclick="{!c.update1}">
        Active: {!v.label1}
    </lightning:button>

    <lightning:button onclick="{!c.update2}">
        <aura:set attribute="label" value="{!'Active: '+v.label2}">
            
        </aura:set>
    </lightning:button>
    
</aura:application>
```

Comment: I am trying to have both the values in the label attribute of one lightning button. I want to set Active to blue color and the v.label1 value to red color.

Comment: @sumchans Put whatever formatting you want in either the aura:set or the body of the button. You can't use both in the same button.